# Triple Nested Loop of Wrapped Letters?

Tags: java

Description:

> Used nested loops to print out a letter pattern as shown below. Wrap
> around the letters from Z to A.

Some possible inputs:

[image]

This is the output for 'X' with '6':

[image]

This is the output for 'C' with '4':

[image]

I'm pretty new to triple nested loops, although I'm aware the first loop is for rows, the second for columns and the third is for the values of the columns. I'm struggling to see why each of my rows have the same amount of letters next to each other. As well as how to wrap the letters to the next without any permeant changes. My Output Below + Code:

[image]

```
public class TriangleFive
{
   private char letter;
   private int amount;

    public TriangleFive()
    {
        this('a',0);
    }

    public TriangleFive(char c, int amt)
    {
        letter = c;
        amount = amt;
    }

    public void setLetter(char c)
    {
        letter = c;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amt)
    {
        amount = amt;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String output="";
        int count = 0;
        int castAscii = (int) letter - count;
        char ch = (char) castAscii;
        for(int i = 0; i< amount; i++){         // Rows

            for(int j = 0; j<amount -count; j++){    // Columns
                output += " ";

                for(int k  =0 ; k < amount -count; k++){    // Values in Columns
                    output +=  ch; 
                }
            }

            output += "\n";
            count++;
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"... I'm pretty new to triple nested loops ..."*

They are not too common, I find that most data can be parsed with just 1 or 2 loops.

> *"... I'm aware the first loop is for rows, the second for columns and the third is for the values of the columns. ..."*

The third loop is not technically required; use the *[String#repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))* method.

You'll need two *[iterative for-loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration)*, and two variables to hold values.
Iterate on *n*, then iterate on *n−Δn*.

- *n* for the amount of tokens
- *Δn* for the decrease in tokens, and token length

Here is an example.

```java
String string(char letter, int n) {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    String newline = System.lineSeparator();
    char copy;
    int n1 = n;
    for (int i = 0, j; i < n; i++) {
        if (i != 0) string.append(newline);
        copy = letter;
        for (j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
            if (j != 0) string.append(' ');
            if (copy - 1 == 'Z') copy = 'A';
            string.append(String.valueOf(copy++).repeat(n - j));
        }
        n1--;
    }
    return string.toString();
}
```

In your code you have assigned *castAscii* to (*letter − count*).
This is incorrect, you want to be increasing *letter* by *Δn*; and not at the declaration.

And, you are then casting *castAscii* to a *char*.
I would remove *ch* and simply cast *castAscii* when it's appended to *output*.

```java
output += (char) castAscii
```

Also, the condition for the inner-most *loop* should be *k < amount - j*.
The repeat amount is relative to *j* and not *Δn*.

```java
for(int k  =0 ; k < amount - j; k++)
```

Finally, after exiting the inner-most *loop*, increment *letter* by 1, and check for *'Z'*.

```java
for(int k  =0 ; k < amount - j; k++){
    output += (char) castAscii;

}
if (castAscii++ == 'Z') castAscii = 'A';
```

Here is the re-factored code.

```java
public String toString() {
    String output = "";
    int count = 0;
    int castAscii = (int) letter;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < amount - count; j++) {
            output += " ";

            for (int k = 0; k < amount - j; k++) {
                output += (char) castAscii;

            }
            if (castAscii++ == 'Z') castAscii = 'A';

        }
        castAscii = letter;

        output += "\n";
        count++;


    }

    return output;
}
```

Output

```
 CCCC DDD EE F
 CCCC DDD EE
 CCCC DDD
 CCCC

 AAAAA BBBB CCC DD E
 AAAAA BBBB CCC DD
 AAAAA BBBB CCC
 AAAAA BBBB
 AAAAA

 BBBBBBB CCCCCC DDDDD EEEE FFF GG H
 BBBBBBB CCCCCC DDDDD EEEE FFF GG
 BBBBBBB CCCCCC DDDDD EEEE FFF
 BBBBBBB CCCCCC DDDDD EEEE
 BBBBBBB CCCCCC DDDDD
 BBBBBBB CCCCCC
 BBBBBBB

 XXXXXX YYYYY ZZZZ AAA BB C
 XXXXXX YYYYY ZZZZ AAA BB
 XXXXXX YYYYY ZZZZ AAA
 XXXXXX YYYYY ZZZZ
 XXXXXX YYYYY
 XXXXXX

 ZZZZZZZZ AAAAAAA BBBBBB CCCCC DDDD EEE FF G
 ZZZZZZZZ AAAAAAA BBBBBB CCCCC DDDD EEE FF
 ZZZZZZZZ AAAAAAA BBBBBB CCCCC DDDD EEE
 ZZZZZZZZ AAAAAAA BBBBBB CCCCC DDDD
 ZZZZZZZZ AAAAAAA BBBBBB CCCCC
 ZZZZZZZZ AAAAAAA BBBBBB
 ZZZZZZZZ AAAAAAA
 ZZZZZZZZ
```